# apex action function not calling controller method

Tags: apex, actionfunction

I am calling the controller method from action function but it is not getting called from the action function.

Please review the below code.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="hhPageMessage" layout="block" rendered="{!message != null && message != ''}" styleClass="{!'page-msg '+severity+'-msg'}">
                                    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!message}" />
                                </apex:outputPanel>

<div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn status btn-secondary btn-apply" onclick="openCancelPopup(); return false;">Cancel</button>
                                            </div>

<div id="cancelPopup" class="modal-cancel">
                                <div class="modal-content-cancel text-center">
                                    <span class="close" onclick="closeCancelPopup();">&times;</span>
                                    <h4 class="cancel-h4">Are you sure you want to cancel?</h4>
                                    <label class="cancel-label">You cannot continue the same application if you cancel.</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-secondary cancel" onclick="cancelApp();return false;">Cancel Application</button>
                                            <apex:actionFunction name="cancelInfoApp" oncomplete="callMethod()" action="{!cancelApplication}"  reRender=“cancelInfoApp,hhPageMessage”/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-secondary continue-app" onclick="closeCancelPopup()">Continue Application</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
<script>
function cancelApp(){
                console.log('Cancelled Called');
                cancelInfoApp();
            } 
</script>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public PageReference cancelApplication(){
        severity = 'error';
        try{
            app.Application_Status__c = 'Cancelled';
            app.Cancellation_Date__c = System.today();
            update app;

            ApplicationModel am = new ApplicationModel(app.Id);
            am.evalTransitionAct();
            am.updateApplicationBatchSafe();

            VK 5262020 Email Notification Upon Cancelled Application (EVORP2NJ-140).
            EV_ApplicationController.sendCancellationEmail(clientRec);
            System.debug('Application Cancelled called');
            PageReference pr = new PageReference('EV_MyDashboard');
            return pr;
        }catch(Exception e){
            new ExceptionLogger('EV_IncomeInfoController', 'cancelApplication', app.Id, null, e).createExceptionRecord();
            message = e.getTypeName()+' '+ e.getMessage()+' = '+e.getStackTraceString();
            System.debug('Exception due to====='+e.getMessage()+e.getLineNumber());
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The action function isn't necessary here, you can just:

```
<apex:commandButton 
  class="btn-secondary cancel" 
  oncomplete="callMethod()" 
  action="{!actincelApplication}" 
  reRender=“cancelInfoApp,hhPageMessage”>
    Cancel Application
</apex:commandButton>
```

Your original method should work, too, but without an error message, it's difficult to tell why it's not working. Is your `apex:actionFunction` between an `apex:form`? That could cause problems if it's not. Context is important here, and we don't have enough of it.